# How do I solve the average number of attempts to succeed when the probability increases with each failure?

Tags: probability

Our base probability of success begins at .03 and each failed attempt increases the probability by .002 so that the second attempt has a probability of .032, the third .034, and so on. (The trials just end, or alternatively a new series must be started at the initial probability of .03 once we have a success.) How can I solve for the average number of attempts needed to succeed once?

Typical hypergeometric calculators don't seem to work for this type of problem. Obviously the answer has to be lower than 33.33 (1/.03) since that would be the average number of attempts when the probability remains static, and increasing probability with failure must reduce the number of average attempts to succeed. I thought perhaps we average the initial number of average attempts with the final number of expected attempts (1) when the maximum number of attempts have been made because the probability has reached 1, but it seems to me that this couldn't be the answer without further modification to this approach since it would give the same answer regardless of how much the increase in probability per failure was set to. I would guess we need to do something along these lines to calculate an average of the average number of attempts at each stage, but I'm not sure exactly how this would work or to write a calculation or code for this.

Comment: The probability to succeed firstly at the kth time  is $P(X=k)=0.97^{k-1}\cdot (0.03+(k-1)\cdot (0.002)$, with the domain $1\leq k\leq 27$. Do you agree? For k>27 the cdf indeed exceeds 1.